# Select data from char position to the next

Tags: string, text, teradata

I have a column which is a text like this-

```
Col = '/a/bbb/cc/aaa/ddd'
```

I want to output only **bbb**. That is everything between 2nd "/" and 3rd "/". How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use

```
STRTOK('/a/bbb/cc/aaa/ddd', '/', 2)
```

or

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR('/a/bbb/cc/aaa/ddd', '[^/]+',1,2)
```

Are consecutive delmiter possible, i.e. `'//bbb/cc/aaa/ddd'`?
If yes, is `bbb` still the correct result?

Comment: STRTOK('/a/bbb/cc/aaa/ddd', '/', 2) worked perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use SUBSTRING_INDEX function (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index)

Example:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX('/a/bbb/cc/aaa/ddd','/',3),'/',-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **<kbd>[SUBSTRING_INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index)</kbd>**

**Query**

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(
           SUBSTRING_INDEX(
               column_name, '/', 3
    ), '/', -1
) AS new_column_name
FROM table_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have *Oracle SQL Developer(Version 4.0.0.13)* and it doesn't recognize method *SUBSTRING_INDEX*, so i had to do it with the help of the following method:
        **SUBSTR(your_string,starting_index, length)**.

But we need to find *starting_index* and *length* first.
     I used **INSTR(your_string,'string_to_find'[,starting_index])** for that.

First i found the index of first "/" like that :

```
        SELECT INSTR('/a/bbb/cc/aaa/ddd', '/') from dual;
```

The index of second "/"(starting index will be the result of this query +1):

```
        SELECT INSTR('/a/bbb/cc/aaa/ddd', '/',
          (SELECT INSTR('/a/bbb/cc/aaa/ddd', '/')+1 FROM dual
          ))
        FROM dual;
```

The length of the string between second and third '/' will be the *index of third '/' - index of second '/' - 1*:

```
        (SELECT INSTR('/a/bbb/cc/aaa/ddd', '/',
        (SELECT INSTR('/a/bbb/cc/aaa/ddd', '/',
          (SELECT INSTR('/a/bbb/cc/aaa/ddd', '/')+1 FROM dual
          ))+1
        FROM dual
        ))
       FROM dual
       ) -
       (SELECT INSTR('/a/bbb/cc/aaa/ddd', '/',
        (SELECT INSTR('/a/bbb/cc/aaa/ddd', '/')+1 FROM dual
        ))
       FROM dual
       )-1
```

Finally, i ended up with this code:

```
    SELECT SUBSTR('/a/bbb/cc/aaa/ddd',
  (SELECT INSTR('/a/bbb/cc/aaa/ddd', '/',
    (SELECT INSTR('/a/bbb/cc/aaa/ddd', '/')+1 FROM dual
    ))
  FROM dual
  )+1,
  (SELECT INSTR('/a/bbb/cc/aaa/ddd', '/',
    (SELECT INSTR('/a/bbb/cc/aaa/ddd', '/',
      (SELECT INSTR('/a/bbb/cc/aaa/ddd', '/')+1 FROM dual
      ))+1
    FROM dual
    ))
  FROM dual
  ) -
  (SELECT INSTR('/a/bbb/cc/aaa/ddd', '/',
    (SELECT INSTR('/a/bbb/cc/aaa/ddd', '/')+1 FROM dual
    ))
  FROM dual
  )-1)
FROM dual;
```

*P.S. I know it's very ugly, but who knows, maybe it can help anybody somehow :) *

Comment: There's a 4th option for `INSTR`, *[occurance]*, simply use `2` for the 2nd or `3` for the 3rd `/`. And Oracle also supports `REGEXP_SUBSTR`